# How do I validate a strong login password in Power Builder?

Tags: regex, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-2017

I need to validate the below rules for my login password:
**Passwords should be a minimum of eight (8) characters and max 15 chars and it should contain the below in it:**

- English upper case letters (e.g., A, B, C, ...Z)
- English lower case letters (e.g., a, b, c, ...z)
- Westernized Arabic numerals (e.g., 1, 1, 2, ...9)
- Non-alphanumeric ("special characters") (e.g., ?,!,%,$,#, etc)
- Enforces at least a minimum of four (4) changed characters
  when new passwords are changed.
- Prohibits password reuse for six (6) iterations prior to reuse.

Its challenging to address all these rules in a single regex. Please suggest a efficient working option.

I am using Appeon PowerBuilder 2022 R2.

Comment: Your last requirement won't be in the regex.  You are going to have to save/encrypt previous passwords somewhere.

Comment: @Matt Balent thank you so much for checking on this. Could you please help me with the regex for the remaining rules? I am not able to cover special characters in my regex.

Comment: I'm by no means a regex expert.  To my knowledge there isn't a 'special' flavor for PB.  You may wish to find a regex forum and ask there.